# Nodejs only 4 remote http request executed simultaneosly

Tags: node.js, concurrency, threadpool, libuv

I am trying to execute multiple simultaneous request using below NodeJS code, but from the output I can see that the below request are executed in bunch of 4.
Why is this happening?

Also I have changes default libuv thread pool size to 7.

```
const http = require("http");
const rq = require("request");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.write("Server started");
  var start = process.hrtime();
  rq("https://stream101.herokuapp.com/5.php", {
    pool: {
      maxSockets: 20
    }
  }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (res) {
      var end = process.hrtime(start);
      console.log(body);
      console.log("in time : %ds", end[0] + end[1] / 1e9);
    }
  });
  res.end();
}).listen(8081);
```

The `stream101.herokuapp.com` here just echos content after sleep of 5 seconds.

This is how my node application is started :

```
set UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=7 && node index.js
```

Node console output:

```
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 6.075168388s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 6.079874785s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 6.077171028s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 6.420050492s

Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 10.966390463s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 10.967194215s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 10.998825902s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 11.42817129s

Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 16.353070153s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 16.440429564s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 16.643850903s
Streaming after 5 seconds
in time : 16.624362216s
```

Apache benchmark command for the above test case :

```
ab -n12 -c5 http://localhost:8081/
```

Is there any issue related to libuv thread pool, since it migt be used for heruko dns query?

Comment: The threadpool is irrelevant 99.9% of the time. The problem is almost always how you're handling things.

Comment: ok, but than what thing is stopping nodejs to execute more than 4 request concurrently.

Comment: Start changing things to find out where the bottleneck is. For example, swap out your URL with `http://example.com/` or some other site. Maybe Heroku is rate limiting you.